# Wheres the phtml file for 'My Account'

Tags: magento2, phtml

In Magento two which phtml file contains the 'My Account' top nav link?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using/falling back to the blank theme? I'm looking at the Luma theme and the links are Sign in and create an account. If it's the same link as 'sign in' then if you search for 'authorization-link' (the class on the <li>) you should find it in a template. I can't check at the moment, if you can't find it let me know and I'll take a look. Off the top of my head it's in Magento_Customer as Danil said, but I think it's a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link is added with Magento_Customer module via file:

```
view/frontend/layout/default.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check that by enabling template path hints

```
store->configuration->advanced->developer->debug->enabled for storefront .
```

and by inspecting My account with firbug or simple, see the class and search for that class in the template file